# Automatic arrangement of the same type of theorem environments

Tags: environments

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{exe}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{sol}{Solution}

\begin{document}

    \begin{exe}
        \dots 
    \end{exe}

    \begin{sol}
        here the solution for Exercise 1
    \end{sol}   

    \begin{exe}
        \dots 
    \end{exe}

    \begin{sol}
        here the solution for Exercise 2
    \end{sol}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way (a switch) to automatically reorder the theorem environments by type without reordering them manually, that means to get the same output as

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{exe}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{sol}{Solution}

\begin{document}

    \begin{exe}
        \dots 
    \end{exe}   

    \begin{exe}
        \dots 
    \end{exe}

    \begin{sol}
        here the solution for Exercise 1
    \end{sol}

    \begin{sol}
        here the solution for Exercise 2
    \end{sol}

\end{document}
```

?

**Update:**

Actually I need a "switch" for this one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{exe}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{sol}{Solution}

\begin{document}

    \begin{exe}
        \dots 
    \end{exe}

    \bigskip

    \begin{sol}
        here the solution for Exercise 1
    \end{sol}   

    \bigskip

    \begin{exe}
        \dots 
    \end{exe}

    \bigskip

    \begin{sol}
        here the solution for Exercise 2
    \end{sol}

\end{document}
```

so that it has the same output as

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{exe}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{sol}{Solution}

\begin{document}

    \begin{exe}
        \dots 
    \end{exe}   

    \bigskip

    \begin{exe}
        \dots 
    \end{exe}

    \bigskip

    \begin{sol}
        here the solution for Exercise 1
    \end{sol}

    \bigskip

    \begin{sol}
        here the solution for Exercise 2
    \end{sol}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can gather the text of the solutions and print them at a certain point.

This can be accomplished with `environ`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newtheorem{exe}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{printsol}{Solution}

\NewEnviron{sol}{%
  \xdef\solutionsuptonow{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\solutionsuptonow}%
    \noexpand\begin{printsol}%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
    \noexpand\end{printsol}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\solutionsuptonow}{}
\newcommand{\printsolutions}{\solutionsuptonow\gdef\solutionsuptonows{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\dots 
\end{exe}

\begin{sol}
here the solution for Exercise 1
\end{sol}   

\begin{exe}
\dots 
\end{exe}

\begin{sol}
here the solution for Exercise 2
\end{sol}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different coding that adds spaces between exercises and solutions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,xparse}

\newtheorem{printexe}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{printsol}{Solution}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{exe}
 {
  \thrash_add:NnV \g_thrash_exercises_seq {exe} \BODY
 }
\NewEnviron{sol}
 {
  \thrash_add:NnV \g_thrash_solutions_seq {sol} \BODY
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printexercises}{}
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \g_thrash_exercises_seq { \bigskip }
  \bigskip
  \seq_use:Nn \g_thrash_solutions_seq { \bigskip }
  \seq_gclear:N \g_thrash_exercisess_seq
  \seq_gclear:N \g_thrash_solutions_seq
 }

\seq_new:N \g_thrash_exercises_seq
\seq_new:N \g_thrash_solutions_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \thrash_add:Nnn
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn #1 { \begin{print#2}#3\end{print#2} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \thrash_add:Nnn { NnV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\dots 
\end{exe}

\begin{sol}
here the solution for Exercise 1
\end{sol}   

\begin{exe}
\dots 
\end{exe}

\begin{sol}
here the solution for Exercise 2
\end{sol}

\printexercises

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Why not just `\newcommand{\solutionsuptonow}` instead of the two lines and in the end `\solutionsuptonow` instead of `\printsolutions`? It works, too.

Comment: @Thrash You want to clear the container of solutions up to now and not print again and again the old solutions, don't you? `;-)`

Comment: I don't understand your question, but I'm a LateX layman.
Another question: What if I have a `\bigskip` between the theorem environments?

Comment: @Thrash The `\solutionsuptonow` macro is loaded with the solutions found so far;  if you don't clear it once the solutions are printed, the next set of solutions will carry over the old ones. I'm not sure *where* you mean to place `\bigskip`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I just wondered where the additional 's' in `\solutionsuptonows` came from because I didn't find it elsewhere. But it seems to be understood by the `environ` package(?)
See my updated original post for the `\bigskip`.

Comment: @Thrash What do you mean by “a switch”?

Comment: In the original sense, so that the solutions are placed together after all the exercises first, but with the only difference that between each two consecutive of all environments should be a `\bigskip` now.

Comment: @Thrash Added the code

Comment: Thanks, but now the space between the two exercises got bigger. I want each two consecutive environments to be separated by `\bigskip`. Is that possible without changing the original body document (unless the last addition of `\printsolutions` of course)?

Comment: @Thrash Changed the coding.

Comment: In the name of a friend: Thanks for your answer, in particular for pointing him towards the package `environ`. This package broadly expands his capability :)